# Tablesorter: child rows above total

Tags: mysql, tablesorter

I get a MySQL query with detail rows and total. I would love to use Tablesorter child rows functionality to hide the details rows but face the problem that need to convert the csv file into html (no problem with that) but my total rows are at the bottom of every list of detailed rows, not above.

The question is, can I use Tablesorter child rows in a way that clicking the link related upper rows unfold?

My sample table (before converting it to html) is:

```
n_cli   n_inv                          date_inv     date_due        eur       +exp
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10289   21222321-1                   2012-10-04   2012-12-30   1,031.05   1,072.29 
10289   21222479-1                   2012-10-09   2012-12-30     257.28     267.57 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total   CUSTOMER1 NAME                                         1,288.33   1,339.86 

10416   21110039-1                   2011-06-22   2011-06-22     136.28     145.28 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total   CUSTOMER2 NAME                                           136.28     145.28
```

By the way, can I use Child Rows with three levels of details? for instance, "total sales per customer / total per invoice/ product lines per invoice" ?

Thanks,

EDITED: This is the source (sample) file:

```
n_cli;n_inv;date_inv;date_due;eur;+exp
10289;21222321-1;2012-10-04;2012-12-30;1,031.05;1,072.29
10289;21222479-1;2012-10-09;2012-12-30;257.28;267.57
Total;CUSTOMER1 NAME;;;1,288.33;1,339.86
10416;21110039-1;2011-06-22;2011-06-22;136.28;145.28
Total;CUSTOMER2 NAME;;;136.28;145.28
```

And my html, which is obviously not working as I am unable to:

1. Edit the CSVTOTABLE process through the loadComplete function (¿?) in
   order to tag the rows to show and the rows to hide.
2. Hide the upper rows (above Total) instead of bottom rows.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/ts/css/theme.default.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/csv/js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>

   <script>
   $(function() {
      $('#tabla1').CSVToTable('dat.txt',
   {
   startLine: 0,
   separator: ";"
   }
   ).bind("loadComplete",function() {
      $(document).find('#tabla1').tablesorter({widgets:
      ["zebra", "stickyHeaders"]});
   });;
   });
   </script>

   </head>
   <body>

   <div>
   <table id="tabla1" class="tablesorter">
   </div>

   </table>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to convert the csv file into a table? And yes, tablesorter can have multiple child rows and it wouldn't be difficult to unfold them.

Comment: @Mottie Please check the edit of the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can use the CSVToTable load complete callback function to modify the table however you want.

I put together this code & [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/595/)* to show how you can assign child rows and make the rows above the total collapsible:

```
$(function () {

  $('table')
  .CSVToTable('csv.txt', {
    startLine: 0,
    separator: ';'
  })
  .bind("loadComplete", function () {
    $('table')
      .find('td:contains("Total")')
      .each(function () {
        var $cell = $(this).prepend('<i/>'),
        $totalRow = $cell.parent().addClass('totals tablesorter-childRow'),
        group = $totalRow.prevUntil('.totals');
        group.last().addClass('tablesorter-parentRow');
        group.slice(0, -1).addClass('tablesorter-childRow');
      }).end()
      .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ["zebra", "stickyHeaders"]
      })
      .find('tr.totals').click(function () {
        $(this)
        .toggleClass('collapsed')
        .prevUntil('.totals').toggle();
      });
  });

});
```

*The demo isn't using the CSVToTable script, but the added HTML would be the same.

The arrow inside the "Total" cell is styled by css, so you can change them as desired:

```
/* collapsed arrow */
tr.totals.collapsed td i {
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #888;
  border-right: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
tr.totals td i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #888;
  border-right: 4px solid #888;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

---

Update: Because you are folding the rows up, you'll need a custom parser to find the custom names in the last row instead of the first, so it sorts properly. Here is the parser to use and an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/597/)

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'findname',
    format: function (s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var $cell = $(cell).parent().nextAll('tr.totals').eq(0).find('td').eq(cellIndex);
        return $cell.text();
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'text'
});
```

---

Update #2: Well, you'll need another parser for numeric columns so they sort properly as well; here's an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/598/):

```
$(function () {

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'findname',
        format: function (s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
            var $cell = $(cell).parent().nextAll('tr.totals').eq(0).find('td').eq(cellIndex);
            return $cell.text();
        },
        type: 'text'
    });

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'findnumber',
        format: function (s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
            var $cell = $(cell).parent().nextAll('tr.totals').eq(0).find('td').eq(cellIndex);
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat($cell.text(), table);
        },
        type: 'numeric'
    });

    $('table')
    .CSVToTable('csv.txt', {
        startLine: 0,
        separator: ';'
    })
    .bind("loadComplete", function () {
        $('table')
            .find('td:contains("Total")')
            .each(function () {
            var $cell = $(this).prepend('<i/>'),
                $totalRow = $cell.parent().addClass('totals tablesorter-childRow'),
                group = $totalRow.prevUntil('.totals');
            group.last().addClass('tablesorter-parentRow');
            group.slice(0, -1).addClass('tablesorter-childRow');
        }).end()
       .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            headers: {
                1: { sorter: 'findname' },
                4: { sorter: 'findnumber' },
                5: { sorter: 'findnumber' }
            },
            widgets: ["zebra", "stickyHeaders"]
        })
        .find('tr.totals').click(function () {
            $(this)
                .toggleClass('collapsed')
                .prevUntil('.totals').toggle();
        });
    });

});
```

---

Update #3

To style the parent and child rows separately, you can use the applied class names `tablesorter-parentRow` and `tablesorter-childRow`, but to avoid confusion, I renamed the `tablesorter-parentRow` to `tablesorter-firstChildRow` because within the plugin it is actually the parent row, but for styling purposes, it would be better to name it as a child row since we're working form the bottom up. The "Totals" row also has the class name `tablesorter-childRow` applied to it, so in order to differentiate it you can use the `totals` class name instead.

Anyway, here is an updated demo with the class name change and css, as well as the addition to make sure it only targets cells in the tbody (`.find('tbody td:contains("Total")')`)

```
/* child row styling */
.tablesorter-firstChildRow td, .tablesorter-childRow td {
    color: red;
}
/* Totals row */
tr.totals td {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's been really kind. My tables now look really great. May I ask if there any way to load the table in collapsed mode as default, to avoid having to fold all the childrows clicking in all parentrows to have a nice picture with the totals? Thanks!

Comment: You can just add a `.click()` after the `click` function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/596/)). I do have a concern though... the table will sort by the top row `n_inv` number instead of the customer name. You'll probably need to add a parser to grab the data from the total row.

Comment: My respects and gratitude for your work! Working awesome now.

Comment: Hi @Mottie and sorry for coming back: I am afraid there's an issue when Tablesorter tries to sort the table, mixing parent and child rows. Please check following snapshots and 399.26 total value: [image1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2856990/2013-04-06_181328_.png), [image2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2856990/2013-04-06_181400_.png). Is there any way to force tablesorter to use only parent lines while sorting? Thanks again.

Comment: @jm_ Try the parser I shared and assign it to whatever column that has your totals.

Comment: Already added the parser code and set type to numeric, but I am unable to see where to assign the column in your code: sorry, not skilled enough with javascript :(

Comment: Opps, the number parser will need to return a number instead of a string, so you'll need to use another parser... I'll update my answer above

Comment: Now that's perfect. Yo can add it to your Github examples ;) Thanks!

Comment: Hi again @Mottie. A couple of questions: 1.Is there any way to apply different css to child rows and parent rows? 2. Can I avoid tfoot row to be treated as a normal row beeing mixed with others when I sort the table? thanks!

Comment: In the demos I shared, a class of `tablesorter-childRow` and `tablesorter-parentRow` are being used, just add css to target them for styling. The tfoot should not be included in the groupings.. umm unless it contains "Total"... in that case, I added Update #3 above with the css for styling the rows separately.

Comment: Thanks @Mottie. I am trying to add filters to that table: can you imagine any way to force filter to look only in total rows and do not unfold the details rows unless they are clicked? Thanks again!

Comment: Try setting the [`filter_useParsedData` widget option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-useParsedData) to `true`

Comment: Well, I don't think the filter widget will do what you need. I would have to rewrite a bunch of its code, which I don't have the time to do. Sorry.

Comment: Of course! your help has been huge along my process to add Tablesorter  to my data. I only can thank you one more time!